# How do I set a default tab in BottomNavigation bar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have 5 tabs currently, how do I set the a default tab when launching the app? lets say I want the account tab to be the default tab when opening the app.

How to I do that? Btw, Im using WebView plugin to display a site's content.

Below is the code of my main.dart file. Ive tried searching and all but the solutions I found wont work for me (I think im searching the wrong words. Also, I am new to flutter) Thank you very much!

```
import 'package:syncshop/widgets/cart_page.dart';
import 'package:syncshop/widgets/categories_page.dart';
import 'package:syncshop/widgets/home_page.dart';
import 'package:syncshop/widgets/profile_account.dart';
import 'package:syncshop/widgets/search_page.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
int _selectedPage = 0;
final _pageOptions = [
  HomeScreen(),
  CategoriesPage(),
  SearchPage(),
  CartPage(),
  ProfileAccount(),
];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Sync Shop',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
      body: _pageOptions[_selectedPage],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          currentIndex: _selectedPage,
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState((){
      _selectedPage = index;
            });
          },
          items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text("Home"),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.category), title: Text("Categories"),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.search), title: Text("Search"),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart), title: Text("Cart"),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle), title: Text("Profile"),
          ),
          ],
          ),
      ),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to programmatically select BottomNavigationBar Tab in Flutter instead of built in onTap callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50961158/how-to-programmatically-select-bottomnavigationbar-tab-in-flutter-instead-of-bui)

Answer (score 2):

You can override `initState` function of `State` and can put some initial codes there.

So for your example, can do this.

...

```
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
    int _selectedPage = 0;
    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _selectedPage = 4;
    }
```

...

Answer (score 2):

When you creating BottomNavigationBar set this.currentindex to index that you want

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentindex=1,//This line, it's default 0
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          currentIndex: _selectedPage,
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedPage = index;
            });
          },
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use tab controller.

First you need to extend `TickerProviderStateMixin` in class.

```
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

}
```

Then define TabController like,

```
_tabController = new TabController(length: _tabLength, vsync: this, initialIndex: 1);
```

and finally set controller in your `TabBarView`

```
controller: _tabController,
```

Comment: should I create this part in the above part of my code?

class _myPageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin{

}

Comment: check answer i made changes in it, add `with TickerProviderStateMixin ` after `State<MyApp>`

Comment: sorry for the late reply, will probably use this in the future

Answer (score 0):

Here you initialize the default tab

```
int _selectedPage = 0;
```

You can change it to any tab you wish, If you want Profile

```
int _selectedPage = 4;
```

Comment: This fixed my problem. Another question,  using ChyperX answer, should I remove the: int _selectedPage = 0;

then using his way will it work just the same?

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncshop/widgets/cart_page.dart';
import 'package:syncshop/widgets/categories_page.dart';
import 'package:syncshop/widgets/home_page.dart';
import 'package:syncshop/widgets/profile_account.dart';
import 'package:syncshop/widgets/search_page.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _selectedPage = 4;

  final _pageOptions = [
    HomeScreen(),
    CategoriesPage(),
    SearchPage(),
    CartPage(),
    ProfileAccount(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Sync Shop',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: _pageOptions[_selectedPage],
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          currentIndex: _selectedPage,
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedPage = index;
            });
          },
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              title: Text("Home"),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.category),
              title: Text("Categories"),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              title: Text("Search"),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
              title: Text("Cart"),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
              title: Text("Profile"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```